# How Nominatim calculates addresses

Tags: openstreetmap, osmosis, nominatim

I have imported OpenStreetMap data for the country Switzerland via osmosis in my MySQL database.

Now I want to look for a specific address in that database, but I can't find a way to get the whole address (street, postcode, town ..).

For  example, the address I'm talking about is: `Street: Archstrasse, town: Grenchen, postcode: 2540, county: Amtei Solothurn-Lebern, country: Schweiz`.

```
<!-- language: lang-sql -->
select * from current_way_tags where way_id = 162530695;> &nbsp;

+-----------+----------+-------------+&nbsp;

| way_id    | k        | v           |&nbsp; 

+-----------+----------+-------------+&nbsp;

| 162530695 | cycleway | lane        |&nbsp; 

| 162530695 | highway  | primary     |&nbsp;

| 162530695 | name     | Archstrasse |&nbsp;

| 162530695 | ref      | 5           |&nbsp;

+-----------+----------+-------------+&nbsp;
```

Comment: https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=Archstrasse,Grenchen,2540,Amtei%20Solothurn-Lebern,Schweiz&format=xml&polygon=1&addressdetails=1&extratags=1&format=html

Comment: thx for the link. But i mean on the Database side. i mean how to get all the Data for a given Adress.

Comment: can you edit the question to make what you are trying to do clearer

Comment: hi @iant, i have edited my question. I hope its clearer for you now.

Answer (score 3):

Take the link from iant's comment and click on [*details*](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/details.php?place_id=95820550). On the database side, Nominatim calculates an address hierarchy. It does this by looking at [address tags](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Addresses) *on* the object, [associatedStreet relation](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Relation:associatedStreet) *on* the object if present, [boundary relations](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Relation:boundary) *containing* the object in question, and [places](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Places) *containing* the object or being *near* it. And maybe more.

More background information:

- [Nominatim development overview](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Development_overview) in the OSM wiki
- [FAQ entry "How was the address calculated?"](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/FAQ#How_was_the_address_calculated.3F)
- [*Nominatim: Behind the scenes*](http://osm.lonvia.de/presentations/2013-nominatim.html) presentations and slides
- [source code](https://github.com/openstreetmap/Nominatim)

Don't forget that there are other [OSM-based search engines](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Search_engines). Some of them are based on Nominatim, others aren't.

Comment: thx scai for your answer. Addresses with Address Tag are easy. i got this already implemented in my software. But sadly not all Addresses are marked as Adresses. The street in my question is a highway. so i fount the street but i didnt find a way to get the other information.

Comment: @BillySanders: Take a look at [Nominatim's address hierarchy for your street](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/details.php?place_id=85331587) to get a better understanding. As you can see, the address hierarchy contains various places and relations as already explained in my answer.

Comment: Thx for the Answer. Last question. i already taked a look at the address hierarchy of the street am looking for.  In my Database i find the Street/Way "Archstrasse" with way_id "116169254". My Problem is i dont know how to find the related relations like "1683510". There is no foreign_key relation between ways and relations in the Database. Maybe you know how to bypass this problem.

Comment: Correct, there is only a *spatial* correlation. [Relation 1683510](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/1683510) *contains* [way 116169254](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/116169254). This is implicit and can be obtained via a corresponding query of a spatial database. That's what Nominatim is doing during import, performing lots of calculations for generating the address hierarchy. If you don't want to reinvent the wheel then make use of Nominatim's database or take a look at other [OSM geocoders](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Search_engines).