# How does OSM match the address?

Tags: openstreetmap, address

I have downloaded a file from OSM which contains geodata for around 50k addresses, much of which are incomplete.

```
+--------------------+-------+---------------+  
| street             | house | city          |  
+--------------------+-------+---------------+  
| Forest Lane        | 75230 | Dallas        |  
+--------------------+-------+---------------+  
| Rendon Road        |       | Burleson      |  
+--------------------+-------+---------------+  
| Matlock Road       | 76018 |               |   
+--------------------+-------+---------------+  
| Hospital Boulevard | 75051 | Grand Prairie |       
+--------------------+-------+---------------+
```

That table have two more columns for the coordinates, which I have not copied here.

Starting from there, how is the process to match an address? Has it to be an exact match? what it happens if additional info such as house number is provided? I was thinking on making a function for this, but it looks as a complex task.

Comment: I think you should study http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim and http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Development_overview.

Comment: Also see the FAQ entry [How was the address calculated?](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/FAQ#How_was_the_address_calculated.3F), the slides [Nominatim - Behind the scenes](http://osm.lonvia.de/presentations/2013-nominatim.html) and the answer to this [same question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190520/how-nominatim-calculates-addresses). And yes, geocoding is a *very complex* task. Don't try to reinvent the wheel unless you have lots of time and a very good understanding on the topic.